# Vending Machine Change Calculator

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I want to break down the entered integer into coins of different sizes: quarters (25), dimes (10), nickels (5) and pennies (1). But I can't figure out what to do for the nickels and pennies.

For example, input of `87` should output:

> 3 quarters, 1 dime, 0 nickels, 2 pennies

But I get:

> 3 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel, 1 penny.

I want it to check if it is a valid entry, if not, I want it to tell the user to enter it again until it gets the valid entry.
Secondly, if it gives the valid entry, I want it to run the program again, and again, but once it gives an invalid entry, I want the program to ask the user to enter a valid entry.
I managed to get most of it done, but I have trouble figuring out how to make the user take another entry over and over again. My code just stops after the second run.
Please help.

Below is my code:

```
public class VendingMachineChangeCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Scanner takeit = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number from 1 to 99"
            + "\nI will find a combination of coins that equals"
            +"the amount of change ");
        int money = 0;
        System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
        money = takeit.nextInt();

    if(money>0 && money<=99) {
        System.out.println("You have: ");

        int quarter, dime, nickel, penny;

        quarter = money/25;
        money = money %25;

        dime = money/10;
        money = money %10;

        nickel = money/5;
        money = money%5;
        penny = money;

        System.out.println(quarter + " quarters");
        System.out.println(dime + " dimes");
        System.out.println(nickel + " nickles");
        System.out.println(penny + " pennies");

        System.out.print("Good job, enter a new valid integer: ");
        money = takeit.nextInt();                       
}
 else  {System.out.print("Invalid entry, please try again: ");
 money = takeit.nextInt();
 } 
    takeit.close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: subtract quarters and dimes from money (after performing appropriate multiplication) and use that for nickel and penny calculations. The number of nickels is otherwise unrelated to the number of dimes. Likewise with pennies and nickels.

Comment: i did           

            quarter = money/25;
   money = money %25;
  
   dime = money/10;
   money = money %10;
  
   nickel = money/5;
   money = money%5;
   penny = money;
   
and it worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question to improve the readability and also add the coin size information (non-native English speakers might have a difficult time to understand the question without it). I hope you get good answers! (Also, hint: search for greedy algorithm - this is a classical problem solved by it)

Comment: i updated my concerns, can you take a look please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your code is wrong, but you have the right idea.

First question your code should do to break it into coins is:

---

*How many quarters can I fit into "money"*

```
quarter = money/25
```

This part is correct.

---

But after you calculate the amount of quarters, you should subtract it from the total amount of money and then move to the next coin.

*How many dimes can I fit into WHAT'S LEFT of money?*

```
money = money - quarter*25
dimes = money/10
```

---

The same logic applies for the other coins:

```
money = money - dime*10
nickel = money/5
```

---

And so on:

```
money = money - nickel*5
penny = money
```

---

This is a simple and thorough approach to this problem, which could be simplified.
So, complete code:

```
public class VendingMachineChangeCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
Scanner takeit = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a whole number from 1 to 99"
    + "\nI will find a combination of coins that equals"
    +"the amount of change ");
int money = 0;
System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
money = takeit.nextInt();
takeit.close();
System.out.println("You have: ");
int quarter, dime, nickel, penny;

quarter = money/25
money = money - quarter*25;
dime = money/10;
money = money - dime*10;
nickel = money/5;
money = money - nickel*5;
penny = money;

System.out.println(quarter + " quarters");
System.out.println(dime + " dimes");
System.out.println(nickel + " nickels");
System.out.println(penny + " pennies");


    }

}
```

Comment: i did           

            quarter = money/25;
   money = money %25;
  
   dime = money/10;
   money = money %10;
  
   nickel = money/5;
   money = money%5;
   penny = money;
   
and it worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Nickel and pennies should be calculated differently. Try this

```
nickel = ((money%25)%10)/5;
penny = ((money%25)%10)%5;
```

Comment: i did           

                 quarter = money/25;
   money = money %25;
  
   dime = money/10;
   money = money %10;
  
   nickel = money/5;
   money = money%5;
   penny = money;
   
and it worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the correct amount of coins

```
change = 87;
```

Basically all you need is count how much coin you will get and don't forget to count the leftover.

```
quarters           = Math.floor(change / 25);
quarters_leftover  = change % 25;

dimes              = Math.floor(quarters_leftover / 10);
dimes_leftover     = quarters_leftover % 10;

nickels            = Math.floor(dimes_leftover / 5);
nickels_leftover   = dimes_leftover % 5;

penies   = Math.floor(nickels_leftover / 1);
```

Sorry for bad in explaining, my english is not good enough, so I can't explain the detail for you.

**Edited:**

If you want a re-entry you need to put it in a loop. So instead using `if`, you need to change it to `while`, so it'll looping if the condition is met

```
while(money > 0 && money <= 99) {
    System.out.println("You have: ");

    int quarter, dime, nickel, penny;

    quarter = money/25;
    money = money %25;

    dime = money/10;
    money = money %10;

    nickel = money/5;
    money = money%5;
    penny = money;

    System.out.println(quarter + " quarters");
    System.out.println(dime + " dimes");
    System.out.println(nickel + " nickles");
    System.out.println(penny + " pennies");

    System.out.print("Good job, enter a new valid integer: ");
    money = takeit.nextInt();                       
}
```